# Troubles running spring mvc java based configuration in idea local tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I created to simple spring mvc configuration using java based configuration:

Config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.kitchen")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/kitchen/**").addResourceLocations("/kitchen/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:E:/Work/images/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
public class WebMvcAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[0];
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfiguration.class};
}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[]{new CORSFilter()};
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "kitchen/index.html";
    }  
}
```

All files are located in same package. But when I try to deploy in tomcat, nothing is deployed. I am not good in configurations so I would like to ask maybe I forgot something more? I do not want to use `web.xml`, just plain java configuration.

Also there could be problem creating modules and artifacts in in `Idea IDE` I moved not a lot of time ogo to it from eclipse. so here is everithing a little bit different. Here are my configurations of project modules and artifacts, can you please tell me what could be problems in my situation?

Screens:
    [image: module spring]
    [image: module web]
    [image: artifact]

Comment: I would suggest looking into Spring Boot instead of dealing with all the configurations manually : http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/